# Error in deploying app to Heroku, H14 Error

Tags: python, heroku, web-deployment, heroku-cli

I tried to deploy my python app on Heroku but when i open it i get this-[image: error]

and when i check the logs, i get the following -

```
2020-07-28T04:02:40.187477+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" 
method=GET path="/" host=song-generator.herokuapp.com request_id=6359f422-79c7-4f9d-ab3f-399e0079467d 
fwd="223.229.164.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-28T04:02:40.886308+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" 
method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=song-generator.herokuapp.com request_id=9e474e1a-b4b4-4709-8891- 
58e0c3525056 fwd="223.229.164.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

And this is my code in the Procfile -

```
web: gunicorn app:app --preload
```

And when i run `heroku ps:scale web=1`, i get the following -

```
Scaling dynos... !
!    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

I tried all the solutions online but none helped me!! PLease Help

Comment: Are you committing on the master branch?

Comment: Yes i am commiting on the master branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, the procfile was actually a .txt file and that is why it couldnt be detected